# How to pass arguments from a function to the creation of a TRIGGER?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a TRIGGER that responds on an update at a table (**appointments**) which then calls a procedure (**proc1()**). The procedure needs to get arguments in order to insert a new row -based on those arguments- on a different table (**medical_folder**). Procedures can't have arguments, but after a bit of search I found that you can use a method like the following to kinda force your way though:

[Passing arguments to a trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060822202907.GA58475@winnie.fuhr.org)

With the above as my base I made the following UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AppointmentUpdate(docAMKA bigint, patAMKA bigint, dateNtime timestamp, conclusion varchar(500),cure2 varchar(500), drug_id integer)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    patAMKAv2 text;
    drug_idv3 text;
BEGIN
    patAMKAv2 := cast(AppointmentUpdate.patAMKA as text);
    drug_idv3 := cast(AppointmentUpdate.drug_id as text);
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr1 on appointments;
    CREATE TRIGGER tr1 BEFORE UPDATE ON appointments
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc1(patAMKAv2,cure2,drug_idv3);
    UPDATE appointments
    SET diagnosis = conclusion
    WHERE patientamka = patAMKA
        AND doctoramka = docAMKA
        AND t = dateNtime;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc1() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
declare
  newid integer;
BEGIN
  newid =((select max(medical_folder.id) from medical_folder)+1);
  INSERT INTO medical_folder AS Medf(id,patient,cure,drug_id)
  VALUES(newid,cast(TG_ARGV[0] as bigint),TG_ARGV[1],cast(TG_ARGV[2] as integer));
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I run it as is I am getting an error in **proc1()** here `cast(TG_ARGV[0] as bigint)` and it seems that in the UDF instead of sending the value of the arguments it sends the arguments themselves(if for example i do this `EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc1(324,cure2,234);`  INSTEAD OF THIS  `EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc1(patAMKAv2,cure2,drug_idv3);` ). Is there any way that you can force it to get the values instead?

P.S.:I now that this can be done a lot easier without the use of a TRIGGER and just make a UDF that does everything itself but unfortunately I have to do it using a TRIGGER.

P.S.2: I tried using **function_name.variable_name** instead of just **var_name** also tried using **$1, $2, $3, ... , $n**.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to generate unique IDs using that broken anti-pattern of `select max(medical_folder.id) + 1` - use a sequence for that. Using `max()` will not work in a situation where multiple transactions are inserting into that table.

Comment: Dont worry about that, this isn't ment for any kind of  product to be published or anything. This can be resolved further ahead if necessary. As for now my problem is making the process taking the arguments as I want them too. This more of (a lot  more actually) an amature project. Thanks for pointing it out anyway appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`CREATE TRIGGER` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html):

> **arguments**
>   An optional comma-separated list of arguments to be provided to the function when the trigger is executed. The arguments are literal string constants. **Simple names and numeric constants can be written here, too, but they will all be converted to strings.**

http://rextester.com/OCA59277

You might be able to achieve what you are trying with dynamic SQL though ([see `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)). But I believe that you overcomplicate things. What you want to do is simply to get rows or IDs which participated in an `UPDATE` statement. PostgreSQL's DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` & `DELETE`) has a `RETURNING` clause just for that. Also, you can actually write more DML (sub-)statements within a single statement with [writeable CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Something like this should suffice:

```
WITH upd AS (
  UPDATE    appointments
  SET       diagnosis   = conclusion
  WHERE     patientamka = patAMKA
  AND       doctoramka  = docAMKA
  AND       t           = dateNtime
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO medical_folder(patient, cure, drug_id)
SELECT patAMKAv2, cure2, drug_idv3
FROM   upd;
```

*Note*: while writing this I realized that you actually don't use any of the fields from the `UPDATE`, but using `FROM upd` will ensure that as much rows will be inserted into `medical_folder` just as much `appointments` got updated. Which is what your original trigger-based logic did.